# How do I animate the thickness of a stroke in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

i've successfully added transitions to my circles in a node graph, but i'm now trying to animate the mouseover of the connective line.

here's what I've tried:

```
//define the lines:
var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
            .data(dataset.edges)
            .enter()
            .append("line")
            .style("stroke", "#ccc")
            .style("stroke-width", 1)
            .on("mouseover", lineMouseover)
            .on("mouseout", lineMouseout);

//the callback functions for mouseover / mouseout
function lineMouseover() {
    d3.select(this).select("line")
        .transition()
        .duration(100)
        .style("stroke-width", 3);
}
function lineMouseout() {
    d3.select(this).select("line")
        .transition()
        .duration(100)
        .style("stroke-width", 1);
}
```

Nothing seems to happen at all when i mouse over the lines. so, either i'm capturing the line incorrectly, or the attributes i'm animating are the wrong attributes.

any insight into what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What does `lineMouseout` do? Does it _cancel_ the old transition?

Comment: the exact same thing, but with a `stroke-width` of 1

Comment: have you tried without the second selection on the event listener? I mean the second .select("line") after the .select(this) that should be enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, the `this`context in the `lineMouseOver`and `lineMouseOut` functions is the line element. You could simply use `d3.select(this)`to select each line and set its attributes. I wrote a small fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pnavarrc/4fgv4/2

```
svg.selectAll('path')
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append('path')
   .attr('d', function(d) { return line(d.p); })
   .attr('stroke-width', function(d) { return d.w; })
   .attr('stroke', function(d) { return d.c; })
   .on('mouseover', mOver)
   .on('mouseout', function(d) {
       d3.select(this)
           .transition()
           .duration(300)
           .style('stroke-width', d.w);
    });

function mOver(d) {
    d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style('stroke-width', 6);
}
```

Regards,

Comment: thanks for answering. I'm not sure how your fiddle demonstrates the mouseover issue / solution. in your code, you're just setting some lines. was that all the fiddle was supposed to do?

Comment: The fiddle shows how to use d3.select(this) to change the path attributes, instead of using d3.select(this).select('line'). Feel free to elaborate if that doesn't solve your issue, regards.

Comment: @Kristian For the fiddle with the same code as the answer you need version 2 of the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/pnavarrc/4fgv4/2/